# wp trim function

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Ok i have this code currently.

```
<?php

query_posts('category_name=widgets2');

echo "<div id='widgets-wrapper2'><div id='marginwidgets' style='overflow: auto; max-    width: 100%; height: 450px; max-height: 100%; margin: 0 auto;'>";
while (have_posts()) : the_post();
echo "<div class='thewidgets2'>";

echo wp_trim_words( the_content(), $num_words = 0, $more = "..." );

echo '<div style="height: 20px;"></div><a class="button2"     href="'.get_permalink().'">Read More</a></div>';
endwhile;
echo "</div></div>";

?>
```

as you can see, it gets all the post from the category name widgets2 and then it should display it.

and this line

```
echo wp_trim_words( the_content(), $num_words = 100, $more = "..." );
```

should trim the words from the_content() to 100 and add a excerpt at the end character but unfortunately it doesnt work, instead it just display the entire contents that looks untrim at all.

Hope someone here could figured out. Im open in any suggestions, recommendations and all relevant ideas, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the WordPress function `the_content()` echos the content.  Use the function `get_the_content()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

> Disclaimer - I don't have much experience with WordPress at all (but I see you are using PHP)

A native PHP solution might also help you here. The `substr()` function returns part of a string -

```
echo substr($longContent, 0, $numOfChars) . '...';
```

Reference -

- [`substr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)